# How to display "This website needs Microsoft Edge" in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Using group policy and enterprise site settings one can get IE11 to show "This page requires Microsoft Edge" window.

[image: https://winblogs.azureedge.net/win/2015/11/neededge.png]

Source: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/11/23/windows-10-1511-enterprise-improvements/

---

Is it possible to achieve the same behavior from the website itself - some meta headers for example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser maybe use this and display a different page if what you want is true

Comment: As much as it sucks, supporting old browsers is part and parcel of being a web developer.  It's your job to write markup, css, and javascript that works with all browsers, not just your favourite ones.  There are libraries like `lodash` which make this very easy, I might add.

Comment: @AdamBarnes I do agree, but I also think that often, you are unable to comply to this guideline, especially in corporate environments, when using third party tools that you cannot get rid of without exceptional amounts of work. Not every website is a NPM-webpack-built online application with JQuery and Angular.

Comment: I believe you're disagreeing with a point I didn't make, @MarkusAppel.  All I'm saying is that requiring anyone who visit the page, with HTML or similar, to switch browsers, is terrible programming.  If company policy dictates using a specific browser, as shown in the question, that's for the company to do, not the programmer.

Comment: @AdamBarnes, yes, it is terrible programming, but maybe not by the programmer asking this question, but by someone that created a tool 10 years ago that is stil deeply integrated into the site functionality and can't be replaced easily. Even if it is outdated, forcing the user to use a different browser might be the better alternative, especially when the website is not for public end users. This often happens in cascade-structured programming teams.

Comment: Please skip the unhelpful banter about how one should work. There are features that are not supported in IE11 and that's just a fact. While displaying "browser is not supported" is always an option, the behavior mentioned in the question would be better for the user.